# Getting Contacts' creation date and last modified date in the list view

Tags: audience-manager

Is it possible to get the Contacts' creation date and last modified date in the Address Book list view? The OE config file has the below section:

```
  <ContactListColumns>
        <Column field="FIRST_NAME" width="100" />
        <Column field="LAST_NAME" width="150" />
        <Column field="EmailAddress" />
        <Column field="ORGANIZATION" />
        <Column field="SubscribeStatus" width="150" />
        <Column field="BounceStatus" width="150" />
  </ContactListColumns>
```

Is it possible to add the creation & modified date fields to this list?

Comment: Did you try? Use the column name from the CONTACTS db table in tridion_em_email

Comment: Tried adding CREATION_DATE and MODIFICATION_DATE fields in ContactListColumns, columns show up in Audience Manager however there are no values (blank columns). Also where are the column headers defined for display in Audience Manager list view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that only extended details fields can be added to the list, as the [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#docid=concept_4C45EB4BFCA9440C922D75AD1E2672E9&filename=ConfiguringOutboundEmail_ContactListColumns.xml&query=ContactListColumns&scope=&tid=20e9d8da-5c48-402b-9549-411304438daa&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_4C45EB4BFCA9440C922D75AD1E2672E9&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=ContactListColumns&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1371045268245&currentQuery=ContactListColumns&currentScope=) [LOGIN REQUIRED] on the subject, refers only to the CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS

> The name of the field or extended detail field. The name of the
>   extended detail field must correspond exactly with the name of the
>   column in the tridion_cm_email database (CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS
>   table), including case. The following fields are hard-coded in
>   Outbound E-mail: BounceStatus, Enabled, EmailAddress, EmailType, SubscribeStatus

Comment: Indeed, it's Extended Details and a handful of specific fields - as listed in the table on that documentation page. This would be a good enhancement request, though :)

Comment: Thank you Will and Peter. So we created a custom page that calls GetContacts() method and then while looping through the list, creates a contact object for each Contact ID and display the results in a grid. When calling the Contact.GetContacts() or AddressBook.GetContacts() method what is the default sort order in which results are returned? Is it possible to define the sort (on a specific extended_detail or VersionInfo field and the sort order)?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider creating custom columns on the [CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS] table on the [TRIDION_CM_EMAIL] database (if you choose this method, [there are a number of other tables you need to update](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_D3B627C67A3849FB839D1B0B4E97BEFB)).  You could then populate the date on which the contact was populated or modified and add the custom columns to your OutboundEmail.xml configuration file, for example:

```
<ContactDetail name="CREATION_DATE" enableSearch="true"> 
    <Label>Created</Label> 
</ContactDetail> 
<ContactDetail name="MODIFIED_DATE" enableSearch="true"> 
    <Label>Last modified</Label> 
</ContactDetail>
```

Setting ‘enableSearch’ to true will allow the columns to be filtered within the Address Book. This should allow you to also search for dates less than, or more than a specified date.